# How to emit a single object from flatmap to filter in RxSwift?

Tags: swift, alamofire, rx-swift

How to emit a single object from flatmap to filter in rxswift?

I want to get a single object from an object array response at flatmap, and I want to get that single object in order to filter the object based on its type. Can anyone suggest me how to solve this?

Comment: please post some sample code and want you want to accomplish with the code exactly

Comment: Sample code is necessary for this to be anwered properly. Answer below is not even using RxSwift.

Answer (score 0):

To *filter* an object based on its type you can use `filter`. `flatmap`s are usually candidates if you want to transform each element of a list and leave out nils.
In your case, let's say you want to extract a String from a heterogenous array:

```
let sampleArray: [Any] = [1, "123", JSONDecoder()]
let filteredString = sampleArray.filter { (element) -> Bool in
    if let _ = element as? String {
        return true
    }
    return false
}.first
```

Or shorthand:

```
let filteredString = sampleArray.filter { return ($0 as? String) != nil }.first
```

Comment: Actually here i want to fetch each single object , that is here i have a response from alamofire request and the response contains multiple user details of different types. Here i want to fetch each users according to the type. Please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Using the above approach, you can extract a particular type of model from your response list. But like mentioned by @KaraBenNemsi, please post some sample code otherwise it's all speculation.